# how can i decrease memory usage by entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

i made one CMS on .NET4 And Entity Framework. this CMS in now begin used on server with shared memory.

application pool has limited memory so app pool reset when my application reach the memory limit . after trace my app i realize EF use most of memory . is there any way to decrease memory usage of EF or any tweaking?

my sample use of EF :

```
using BICT.Data;
//
public static List<Data.Log> GetList()
{
    using(CMSEntities cms = new CMSEntities())
    {
       return cms.Log.ToList<Data.Log>();
    }
}
```

am i use a wrong way to use EF?

Comment: You should start with memory profiler and find exactly what is going on. This is too broad and you will not get an valuable answer.

Comment: Btw. this looks similar: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/559505/entity-framework-memory-leak

Answer (score 1):

Assuming CMSEntities is your dbContext, then you're using it the right way as it implements the IDisposable interface.

One thing I would suggest is returning an IQueryable instead of a List as then you gain the flexibility of pipelining Linq queries, and **then** actually accessing the database. ([Lazy Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx)).

If you want all of the items, you can call .ToList(), so that option is still available to you.

---

**EDIT**

For example, say I have a User table in my database, I create a wrapper class for accessing the data.

```
namespace Data.Repositories
{
    public class UserRepository : IDisposable
    {
        ColegioDBV2Entities db = new ColegioDBV2Entities();

        public IQueryable<User> FindAllUsers()
        {
            return db.Users;
        }    

        public void Dispose()
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And when I want to access data I do so through this repository class:

```
using (UserRepository repo = new UserRepository())
{
    var result = repo.FindAllUsers().Where(u => u.Username == txtUsername.Text && u.Password == txtPassword.Text);                    
}
```

Once you leave that using block, your context is automatically closed and released.

Comment: and what about memory usage ? IQueryable  make it better or not?

Comment: @Raika: Haven't done benchmarks, but it will be better *when* you find yourself needing to filter data as the filtering takes place in the SQL query itself, and not in your application logic. I doubt it's a significant boost though.

Comment: when i return an IQueryable i get this error : **The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.**

Comment: @Raika: That's because your dbContext is wrapped around a using statement, so it's returning the IQueryable<T> but then closing the connection. See my edit.

Comment: You have to realize the query (via ToList or similar) while it is still in the lifetime of the context (inside its using block).